# Artifactory Publish Android Library with Resources

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library, artifactory

### Problem:

I am trying to create an Android Library which can be included in an application using:

```
// Application's build.gradle
compile 'com.mycompany:mylibrary:1.0.0'
```

In my case, I am using **Artifactory** and I have gotten the above to work fine. The problem is when I try to run the application I a missing resources. The problem seems to be that my library has code that depends on  resources which are not getting included in the jar published to **Artifactory**

```
// Code in library, throws exception because <resource> is not included in the jar
getString(R.string.<resource>)
```

---

### Question:

How can I include the resources in the jar when publishing to **Artifactory**? Currently, it only includes the class files. Here is my current gradle.build for publishing:

```
// Android Library - build.gradle
{
    // ... Other build.gradle settings go here

    //==========================================================
    //  ARTIFACTORY SETTINGS
    //==========================================================

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
                credentials {
                    username = "${artifactory_user}"
                    password = "${artifactory_password}"
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.3"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
            defaults {
                publications ('mavenJava')
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'libs-release'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }

    task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'com.mycompany'
                artifactId 'mylibrary'
                version '1.0.0'
                artifact(sourceJar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also post the file system layout of your project? Especially which folders are under "src", and where the missing resource files are located.

Comment: @Jolta, thanks for commenting. It turned out I needed to produce an .aar when creating an Android dependency library. The .aar file includes everything needed. I've posted my updated build.gradle file below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue. I found my solution [here](http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/6ededc236fe4a68bda28f9aa26e9d0f8-bde760935356551ee8d522debba080e5) and [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/gradle-android-aar/build.gradle).

My original `gradle.build` script was fine for publishing jar files; however, when building an android library for use with other projects you typically want a **.aar** file, **not a .jar** file.

---

In order to have Artifactory publish a **.aar** file I've copied my build.gradle below.

**NOTE:** you must use the `com.android.library` plugin otherwise you'll end up with a **.apk** instead of a **.aar**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    //... Android specific parameters
}

dependencies {
    //... Android specific dependencies
}

//==========================================================
//  ARTIFACTORY SETTINGS
//==========================================================

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'artifactory'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

version = "1.0.0"
group = "com.mycompany"

configurations {
    published
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

artifactoryPublish {
    dependsOn sourceJar
}

artifacts {
    published sourceJar
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publishConfigs('archives', 'published')
            properties = ['build.status': 'integration']
            publishPom = true
            publishIvy = false
        }
    }
}
```